# How do you modify an app that's on the app store without making your users update the app?

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-application

I am working on an mobile app that requires me to change the text displayed either on a weekly or a monthly basis, but I don't want to require the users to have to update the app every day or every week in order to see the changes. I would love suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: Have the app make a network request to a server which returns the current text to display.

Answer (score 0):

As a high-level answer, check the device date and display the proper text, if it is fixed and known ahead of time.

If not, have a file or api call send down the information and the next date of when the server should be checked for the next set of data.